# Proving that a set of vectors is a basis in $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to show that the following set constitutes a basis for the vector space of polynomials up to degree $3$, i.e. $P_3$:

$\{(t-1),(t+1),(t-1)^3,(t+1)^3)\}$

Since $P_3$ is four dimensional, I believe it to be sufficient to show that these monomials are independent, i.e. that

$ \lambda_1*(t-1)+\lambda_2*(t+1) + \lambda_3*(t-1)^3 + \lambda_4*(t+1)^3 = 0\implies 
\lambda_1=\lambda_2= \lambda_3 = \lambda_4 = 0$

What I tried so far was picking specific $t$'s to show that this must follow for my choice of $t$, but so far I haven't found any obvious example which worked.

Comment: However, picking randomly $4$ values for $t$ gives you a basis with probability $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also try to prove that they generate $P_3$:
$$\begin{align}
2\ &=\ (t+1)\ -\ (t-1) \\
t\ &=\ (t+1)\ -1 \\
\dots+6t^2\ &= (t+1)^3\ -\ (t-1)^3 \\
&\dots
\end{align}$$

Comment: but a basis must be minimal, right? I am also not sure I understood your former comment - what do you mean with *four* values for t?

Comment: Yes, minimal. But if you have $4$ vectors in a $4$ dimensional space that either generates the whole or are linearly independent, then it is a basis. Now we can express each one of $1,t,t^2,t^3$ by the given four polynomials.

Comment: For the 4 values: consider the $4\times 4$ matrix
$\left(p_i(t_j)\right)_{i,j}$ where $p_i$'s are the given polynomials. If you find $t_1,\dots,t_4$ such that this matrix is regular (invertible), that proves that the polynomials are linearly independent.

Comment: I will do that. I figured though I can just multiply out everything and regroup, then solve a system of linear equations for four possible scalars lambda1 to lambda4 where it follows that they all most be zero. Will try your method too, though. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good exercise in (what I consider) two of the most important properties in linear algebra:

1. "the matrix representation of a linear transformation with respect to a given basis"
2. "if you know what a linear transformation does to a basis, then you know what it does to everything"

If we can somehow linearly transform the "standard" basis $S$ for $P_3$ into the given basis $B$ here (in an invertible manner) then this will guarantee that $B$ is a basis as well. (Scour your favorite Very Valuable Theorem about invertibility of matrices for this!)

So all we need to do is find an invertible linear transformation that takes $S$ to $B$. We know that a linear transformation is uniquely determined by what it does to a basis (see property 2), and so all we need to do is decide where to send $S$. The most obvious choice is to send the first standard basis element $e_1$ to the first element $(t-1)$ of $B$, the second standard basis element $e_2$ to the second element $(t + 1)$ of $B$, and so on.

This produces a linear transformation $T : P_3 \to P_3$ with the property $T(e_1) = t - 1$, and $T(e_2) = t + 1$, etc. Encoding this as a matrix with respect to the standard basis (see property 1), we get the matrix
$$
[T]_{S} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & ? & ? \\
1 & 1 & ? & ? \\
0 & 0 & ? & ? \\
0 & 0 & ? & ?
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(where I've left the third and fourth columns for you to fill in---remember, the $i$th column simply tells us how to write $T(e_i)$ with respect to the ordered basis $S$).

All that remains is to show that $[T]_S$ is invertible, and I trust that you have a Very Valuable Theorem to help decide whether such a matrix is invertible, as well as why this invertibility gives you both the linear independence and spanning properties of the basis you started with.